# Does HTML tag name has a max size ( length )

Tags: javascript, tags, w3c-validation

i do want to build a validator for HTML tagname ,

```
   vdAPI.get({module:'html',subject:'tag'}).validator=function (tag){
         return !vdAPI.nottags.contains(tag) && (tag.length>0 && tag.length <= vdAPI.MAX_LENGTH_TAG)
    }
```

What is the suitable value of `vdAPI.MAX_LENGTH_TAG`   ?

Comment: AFAIK, the longest is Blockquote, its length is 10 characters, however using angular or javascript you could create your own valid html tag, which I believe it could be of any size.

Comment: <figcaption> also 10 characters, dont know any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html):

> The algorithm described below places **no limit on** the depth of the DOM tree generated, or on **the length of tag names**, attribute names, attribute values, Text nodes, etc. While implementors are encouraged to avoid arbitrary limits, it is recognized that practical concerns will likely force user agents to impose nesting depth constraints.