# Maximum length of a component name in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular is there a maximum length that component names can have? For example: am I going to run into problems with a component name like: `FirstThingSecondThingThirdThingCreateComponent`?

Comment: Don't see any issue except for file name limitation on OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory [there is no limit for a identifier in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809153/maximum-length-of-variable-name-in-javascript) or Typescript

In a similar way, W3C standards [do not set a limit for a tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607977/does-html-tag-name-has-a-max-size-length)

So the only limit you can find is (if you are following the convention of naming the files after the component's class) the file name limitation on your OS ([255 characters](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux), typically)